# Redirect Page if its not open within the Facebook app built in browser

Tags: javascript, facebook

We are using the following code which we found here on Stackoverflow as we have a few plugins on our website that do not play well when opened within the facebooks built in browser. The code allows us to create a specific page that is shown only when a user goes to the site via facebook.

```
<script>
  var ua = navigator.userAgent;

  if (ua.indexOf("FBAN") != -1 || ua.indexOf("FBAV") != -1) {
    if (!window.location.href.match('redirect_fb')) {
      window.location.href = "https://example/redirect_fb/";
    }
  }

</script>
```

The user is asked to open the page with safari or chrome.
However, can anyone help have the example page redirect back the home page url when they leave the facebook browser.

For example
Users goes to facebook page > click on button to view our website > website loads inside facebook browser > user is shown a specific page with instructions asking them to open in default mobile browser > user follows instructions > url redirects to the home page url

Hopefully I have made this clear. hard to put down exactly wheat I need in words.

Thanks

Comment: No, not clear. What do you want to redirect, where and when?

Comment: Sorry! So when the user visits our page within the facebook browser a specific page is shown (https://example/redirect_fb/) the page contains instructions on how to open our website using chrome or safari. when they do this and open the website in chrome for example ( they click on the three dots on the top right and then click "open in chrome" ) the website opens in this browser. However, it is still showing the instructions page https://example/redirect_fb/ we need this page to redirect to another page as they no longer need these instructions.

Comment: So in that page, check again if you are still in the FB in-app browser, and redirect to the homepage if not …

Comment: Exactly what we are after

Comment: So what is the problem then?

Comment: The code above checks if they are in a facebook browser and redirects to this page https://example/redirect_fb/ What we need is code that checks this page https://example/redirect_fb/ and if they are not in a facebook browser redirect them to another page

Comment: not sure how much work that would be, but why not try to make your code work in the facebook in app browser? i would rather create a thread on stackoverflow about it, if there is some problem with it you cannot fix. this sounds just like a workaround.

Comment: Well then _write_ that code …!?! You got everything you need right there already, no?

Comment: _“What we need is code that checks this page example/redirect_fb ”_  - you have code already to check if you are _not_ on that page - so reverse it! _“and if they are not in a facebook browser ”_ - you have code already to check if they _are_ inside it - so reverse it …